# "Limited to" vs. "Limited up to"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

> The total length of a file name should be limited **up** to 31 characters.

1. Whether I should use the word "up" in this sentence?
2. Is there a difference between the sentence above and the same one without "up"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a phrasal verb ["be limited to sth"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/be-limited-to-sth).

While it is not wrong to say "limited up to", it is redundant to add an additional "up". Grammatically, both are correct.

Nevertheless, you can simply say:

> The total length of a file name should be limited to 31 characters.

More examples of the use of "limited to" can be found [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/limited+to).